# How can i understand what version of dotnet a .net based application is using?

Tags: .net

How can i find about a dot net applications prerequisite? 
lately i moved  an application which works fine on my system to another system and upon executing it, the application crashed.I tried installing dot-net frameworks 4, 3.5sp1 and 3.5 ( couldn't install 3 because it was complaining about a newer version being installed ).But still no luck.
So how can i know about it in first place?

Comment: When it crashed, what was the error message?

Comment: How are you executing it, through debug on VS or as an IIS Application?

Comment: @jrummell: "MyApplication" has encountered a problem and needs to close.

Comment: @Grinn: it was a debug version of my project,and by double clicking on its icon , outside VS ( on a different system) i tried to execute it

Comment: You may find a more detailed error message in the [Application Event Log](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722404.aspx).

Comment: Oh, it's a Windows Forms (or Console) app. I assume this is an app to which you have source-code access. I'd go into VS > Solution Explorer > References > view Properties on System, and look at the Version there. Then, check on the other machine to ensure that .NET version is installed (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785). Here's a reference to what the version #'s mean: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_.NET_Framework_versions . Let me know if that works for you and I'll post it as an answer to get credit! :)

Comment: Thanks its helpful ;) but isnt there any way to know what version of dotnet an application is working with? in case we dont have its source code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open [ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), drag and drop the assembly onto the IL DASM window.  Then double-click the MANIFEST node in the window and you will see its referenced assemblies and their version information.

**EDIT**

If you don't have ildasm.exe, another good free option is [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) from JetBrains.  You can drop your assembly onto it's assembly explorer, right-click it and select properties.  You will see the .net framework version in the properties window.

And I have noticed that if you open a .net assembly with a text editor and do a "find" for `.NETFramework` you can pretty reliably find the framework version in the file.

Comment: What if i don't have access to visual studio and thus ildasm.exe as well? what should i do in that case?